# Why is my HTML so poorly formatted when rendered with Smarty?

Tags: php, wamp, smarty, slim, smarty3

Why is my HTML so poorly formatted when viewing the source code?

Working with:

1. [WAMPSERVER (64 BITS & PHP 5.5) 2.5](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
2. [Slim Framework v2](http://docs.slimframework.com/)
3. [RedBeanPHP 4.2](http://www.redbeanphp.com/)
4. [Smarty 3.1.21](http://www.smarty.net/)

---

**index.php:**

```
<?php

// load required files
require 'class/Slim/Slim.php';
require 'class/RedBean/rb.php';

// register slim auto-loader
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

// set up database connection
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slimcms','root','');
R::freeze(true);


// initialize app
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'mode' => 'development'
    ,'debug' => true
    ,'view' => new \Slim\Views\Smarty()
    ,'templates.path' => './templates'
));


$view = $app->view();

$view->parserDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/class/Smarty/';
$view->parserCompileDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/compiled';
$view->parserCacheDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache';



// handle GET request for index
$app->get('/', function() use ($app){
    $books = R::findAll('book');
//print_r($books);
    $app->render('home.tpl',array('books'=>$books));

});


$app->run();
```

---

**templates/home.tpl:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="content">
        {foreach name=aussen item=book from=$books}
            {foreach key=key item=value from=$book}
                {if $key == 'id' }
                    <a href="{$key}/{$value}">{$key}</a>
                {else}{$key}{/if}
            {/foreach}
            <hr />
        {/foreach}
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

---

when i view the **sourcecode via chrome**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
                                                        <a href="id/1">id</a>
                                            rating                            price                            title                        <hr />
                                                        <a href="id/2">id</a>
                                            rating                            price                            title                        <hr />
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would have **expected:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <a href="id/1">id</a> rating price title
        <hr>
        <a href="id/2">id</a> rating price title
        <hr>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Besides debugging, what's the practical purpose of pretty-formatting the HTML? Even for debug, you don't really need it.

Comment: Agree with @axiac, there is no point in making the HTML pretty. The browser has to read it, not you.

Comment: More spaces and bad formatting = more html size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is an answer to the "why" part of the question. Regarding the unspoken "how to fix" part, you better try to find out how to produce smaller HTML, not prettier.**

On compilation, `Smarty` replaces the fragments enclosed by `{` and `}` with PHP code blocks, enclosed in `<?php` and `?>`.

The following Smarty template fragment:

```
<div id="content">
    {foreach name=aussen item=book from=$books}
        {foreach key=key item=value from=$book}
            {if $key == 'id' }
                <a href="{$key}/{$value}">{$key}</a>
            {else}{$key}{/if}
        {/foreach}
        <hr />
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

becomes something like:

```
<div id="content">
    <?php foreach ($books as $book): ?>
        <?php foreach ($book as $key => $value) : ?>
            <?php if ($key == 'id'): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $key; ?>/<?php echo $value; ?>">{$key}</a>
            <?php else ?><?php echo $key; ?><?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <hr />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

*Please note that the PHP code above is not what Smarty generates. The code generated by Smarty is more complex due to the way it stores the variables assigned to the template, the way it handles the properties of the built-in functions, the variables modifiers and the other features it provides.

But for the purpose of this discussion, this oversimplified version of the code is enough. What is important here is that `Smarty` does not change anything outside the `{ ... }` blocks.*

`Smarty` does not break the formatting of your template/HTML code. `PHP` is the one that does it.

`PHP` interprets the blocks of code (enclosed in `<?php` and `?>`) and replaces them with the output they generate, if any. But it also removes a new line character if it is immediately after the PHP closing tag `?>`.

> The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.

*(source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)*

However, the spaces used for indentation of the Smarty tags are not removed neither by `Smarty` nor by `PHP` (because they are not inside tags). They make it to the final HTML and because of the removed newlines they break the format.

Comment: I hadn't thought of newlines accidentally  disappearing, and can't see any obvious effects of that in the example in the question, but this is a good explanation of the steps involved.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question as asked is "why is the code not pretty?" not "how do I make it pretty?", I will give the simple answer:

Smarty (and PHP) is passing through exactly the whitespace you have put into the template; it has no knowledge of the HTML structure you are creating. The only thing that will be stripped out are the Smarty tags themselves.

So for instance if you write this:

```
  [ 
  {if $foo}
        foo
  {else}
        bar
  {/if}
  ]
```

all those spaces will be part of the output, which will be either:

```
  [

        foo

  ]
```

or:

```
  [

        bar

  ]
```

So if you don't want whitespace in your output, don't include it in your input.

One trick is to comment it out:

```
  [{* 
  *}{if $foo}{*
        *}foo{*
  *}{else}{*
        *}bar{*
  *}{/if}{*
  *}]
```

That will result in:

```
  [foo]
```

or:

```
  [bar]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found so far.

=> ~1.1 [Dindent](https://github.com/gajus/dindent)

=> ~0.11 [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#top),

enable in php.ini extension=php_tidy.dll

**index.php: ~1.1 use this:**

```
<?php

// load required files
require 'class/Slim/Slim.php';
require 'class/RedBean/rb.php';
require 'class/Dindent/Indenter.php';                      //<= added

// register slim auto-loader
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

// set up database connection
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slimcms','root','');
R::freeze(true);


// initialize app
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'mode' => 'development'
    ,'debug' => true
    ,'view' => new \Slim\Views\Smarty()
    ,'templates.path' => './templates'
));


$view = $app->view();


$view->parserDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/class/Smarty/';
$view->parserCompileDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/compiled';
$view->parserCacheDirectory = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache';



// handle GET request for index
$app->get('/', function() use ($app){
    $books = R::findAll('book');
//print_r($books);

    //$app->render('home.tpl',array('books'=>$books));
    $indenter = new \Gajus\Dindent\Indenter();             // <= start added
    ob_start();                                            //
    echo $app->render('home.tpl',array('books'=>$books));  //
    $content = ob_get_contents();                          //
    ob_end_clean();                                        //
    echo $indenter->indent($content);                      // <= end added


});


$app->run();
```

**~0.11 use this:**

```
ob_start();
    $app->render('home.tpl',array('books'=>$books));
    $buffer = ob_get_clean();
    $tidy = new tidy();
    $clean = $tidy->repairString($buffer,
        array(
            'indent' => true
            ,'indent-attributes' => true
    ));
    echo $clean;
```

output as **expected:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <a href="id/1">id</a> rating price title 
            <hr />
            <a href="id/2">id</a> rating price title 
            <hr />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: note that increases the execution time from ~0.09 to  ~1.1
Does anyone have a better solution

Comment: yes, learn to indent manually. allow for carriage return and tab characters to actually exist in the html, instead of being inside your php/template engine.